# Unit testing Quartz plugin for Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have some trouble writing the most basic unit test for a job. My problem can be recreated by creating a new job by running `grails create-job my` in the console.

This will create two files

- `MyJob.goovy` (under the default package myApp - resides in test\unit\myApp)
- `MyJobSpec.groovy` (under the default package myApp - resides in grails-app\jobs\myApp)

Now if i try to use the job `MyJob` in the test, as example

```
import myApp.MyJob //This is not resolved

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class MyJobSpec extends Specification {
    def myJob
```

I get the compiler error `Groovy:unable to resolve class MyJob`. Everything so far was automatically created by the plugin. What is going on here? Is there something i did wrong / how do i get this to work?

Using grails 2.3.11.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but use `def` or `MyJob`, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which IDE are you using or if you are running everything on a terminal, but I had similar problems with Eclipse and what you need to do is to add grails-app/jobs to the classpath as a source folder.

Comment: I feel ashamed. Should have been first thing to check. Thank you.